# query on same field with multiple values using RestHighLevelClient

Tags: elasticsearch, resthighlevelclient

I have to filter/query multiple urls on "url" field using Elasticsearch RestHighLevelClient.
I formed my query as below but it is giving 0 records.

```
query.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://localhost:8080/test/*")
                         .field("url")
                        .lenient(true)
                        .escape(true)
                        .analyzeWildcard(true)
                        .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                        .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                        .boost(1.0f));
query.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://www.bbc.com/*")
                     .field("url")
                    .lenient(true)
                    .escape(true)
                    .analyzeWildcard(true)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                    .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                    .boost(1.0f));
```

If I change to below it will give me only matching records url `http://localhost:8080/test/*` as I am setting `Operator.AND` to this and for query on url  `http://www.bbc.com/*` to `Operator.OR`.

```
query.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://localhost:8080/test/*")
                         .field("url")
                        .lenient(true)
                        .escape(true)
                        .analyzeWildcard(true)
                        .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                        .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                        .boost(1.0f));
query.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://www.bbc.com/*")
                     .field("url")
                    .lenient(true)
                    .escape(true)
                    .analyzeWildcard(true)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                    .defaultOperator(Operator.OR)
                    .boost(1.0f));
```

So it is ignoring `http://www.bbc.com/*` filter.

Am I doing any mistake here? How to write multiple queries on same field?

Comment: Please add mapping of index as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `should` rather than `must` in your [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query.

#### What happens in the original query?

The first query you perform actually asks both of the `url` values to be present in a document: it will match if and only if in the same document you have `url: http://localhost:8080/test/` and `url: http://www.bbc.com/`.

This behaviour is normal for a [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query, and is not specific to [`BoolQueryBuilder`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.6.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.html) that I assume you are using.

#### How to do a logical OR of two queries?

In fact, you should use [`BoolQueryBuilder.should()`](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.6.0/org/elasticsearch/index/query/BoolQueryBuilder.html#should(org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilder)) to put these two queries in a logical OR:

```
query.should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://localhost:8080/test/*")
                     .field("url")
                    .lenient(true)
                    .escape(true)
                    .analyzeWildcard(true)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                    .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                    .boost(1.0f));
query.should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://www.bbc.com/*")
                 .field("url")
                .lenient(true)
                .escape(true)
                .analyzeWildcard(true)
                .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                .boost(1.0f));
```

#### How can I combine this with other parts of my query?

As you pointed out in the comment, your query is actually more complex: it must match one of the URL patterns, and results should be boosted if they also match the content.

In order to achieve this you should use two nested bool queries like this:

```
BoolQueryBuilder urlQuery = BoolQueryBuilder();

urlQuery.should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://localhost:8080/test/*")
                         .field("url")
                        .lenient(true)
                        .escape(true)
                        .analyzeWildcard(true)
                        .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                        .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                        .boost(1.0f));

urlQuery.should(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("http://www.bbc.com/*")
                     .field("url")
                    .lenient(true)
                    .escape(true)
                    .analyzeWildcard(true)
                    .fuzziness(Fuzziness.ZERO)
                    .defaultOperator(Operator.AND)
                    .boost(1.0f));

WildcardQueryBuilder wildcardQuery = QueryBuilderswildcardQuery("content", "anyt*");


// here `query` is your original bool query
query.must(urlQuery);
query.should(wildcardQuery);
```

Elasticsearch will interpret this query as something like:

> fetch documents that **must** match either `url query #1` or `url query #2`, and rank higher those that match `wildcardQuery`

#### What does `defaultOperator` have to do with all this?

The `.defaultOperator(Operator.OR)` is actually just Elasticsearch trying to confuse you: it has nothing to do with uniting two queries in a logical OR, but instead is a parameter of [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html):

> **default_operator**
>
> (Optional, string) Default boolean logic used to interpret text in the query string if no operators are specified.

This parameter actually tells Elasticsearch [how to interpret the tokens](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_boolean_operators) *inside* the `queryStringQuery()` that you pass. You can think about the string query as a query in [Lucene query language](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators).

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Madhava I see, looks like you were setting other `should` clauses to the same `query` object. I updated the answer and added a note on how to combine my suggestion with other optional `should`'s. Please check it out!

Comment: Hi Nikolay,
it is working fine. thank you very much.

Comment: @Madhava Glad to hear that! Please feel free to accept the answer so other users of StackOverflow will know that we've got a solution that works for you. And upvote if you found it useful! Thank you!